# Format document on save with Remove unused usings on vscode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I want to setup to fire "format document" and "remove unused usings" on save for C# code on Visual Studio Code. Or add a keyboard shortcut for remove unused usings.

I have added to user settings below.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

This fires format document on save. But I want also to remove unused usings.
VS code warns me if there are unused usings and I can Ctrl + . to popup about remove unused usings.

1. Can I setup fire remove unused usings on save?
2. Can I add a keyboard shortcut for the remove unused usings?

I also added keyboard shortcut for format document.

```
{ "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+f",         "command": "editor.action.formatSelection",
                                  "when": "editorHasDocumentSelectionFormattingProvider && editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" },
```

I want to add Ctrl+R Ctrl+G for remove unused usings. (by Visual Studio defaults). But I don't know how I can configure keyboard shortcut settings...

```
{ "key": "ctrl+r ctrl+g",         "command": "editor.action.???",
                                  "when": "???" },
```

Answer (score 8):

The configuration to remove unused usings must be done through omnisharp.

*Omnisharp settings can be available in two locations:*

**For global settings:**

> For global settings, use `%USERPROFILE%/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json` file

**For project specific settings:**

> use `omnisharp.json` at the root of your workspace

**Settings are the following:**

```
{
     "FormattingOptions": {
         "OrganizeImports": true
     }
}
```

**Other default settings available in 5/5/2020:**

```
{
    "FormattingOptions":  {
        "OrganizeImports":  false,
        "EnableEditorConfigSupport":  false,
        "NewLine":  "\n",
        "UseTabs":  false,
        "TabSize":  4,
        "IndentationSize":  4,
        "SpacingAfterMethodDeclarationName":  false,
        "SpaceWithinMethodDeclarationParenthesis":  false,
        "SpaceBetweenEmptyMethodDeclarationParentheses":  false,
        "SpaceAfterMethodCallName":  false,
        "SpaceWithinMethodCallParentheses":  false,
        "SpaceBetweenEmptyMethodCallParentheses":  false,
        "SpaceAfterControlFlowStatementKeyword":  true,
        "SpaceWithinExpressionParentheses":  false,
        "SpaceWithinCastParentheses":  false,
        "SpaceWithinOtherParentheses":  false,
        "SpaceAfterCast":  false,
        "SpacesIgnoreAroundVariableDeclaration":  false,
        "SpaceBeforeOpenSquareBracket":  false,
        "SpaceBetweenEmptySquareBrackets":  false,
        "SpaceWithinSquareBrackets":  false,
        "SpaceAfterColonInBaseTypeDeclaration":  true,
        "SpaceAfterComma":  true,
        "SpaceAfterDot":  false,
        "SpaceAfterSemicolonsInForStatement":  true,
        "SpaceBeforeColonInBaseTypeDeclaration":  true,
        "SpaceBeforeComma":  false,
        "SpaceBeforeDot":  false,
        "SpaceBeforeSemicolonsInForStatement":  false,
        "SpacingAroundBinaryOperator":  "single",
        "IndentBraces":  false,
        "IndentBlock":  true,
        "IndentSwitchSection":  true,
        "IndentSwitchCaseSection":  true,
        "IndentSwitchCaseSectionWhenBlock":  true,
        "LabelPositioning":  "oneLess",
        "WrappingPreserveSingleLine":  true,
        "WrappingKeepStatementsOnSingleLine":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInTypes":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInMethods":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInProperties":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAccessors":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousMethods":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInAnonymousTypes":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInObjectCollectionArrayInitializers":  true,
        "NewLinesForBracesInLambdaExpressionBody":  true,
        "NewLineForElse":  true,
        "NewLineForCatch":  true,
        "NewLineForFinally":  true,
        "NewLineForMembersInObjectInit":  true,
        "NewLineForMembersInAnonymousTypes":  true,
        "NewLineForClausesInQuery":  true
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually remove them, it just sorts them.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that, writing today, there's no plugin on the [VSCode Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=C%23%20using&target=VSCode&sortBy=Relevance) - nor a built in setting/functionality offering what you want regarding "unused usings" behaviour like in the full blown Visual Studio.

My advice would be to ask for this functionality at the official Microsoft plugin called "[OmniSharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)" (default C# plugin that also powers other editor's C# functionality): https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues.
  *Side note: there is an issue open there about "unused usings", to disable the warnings it generates: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/315*

Or to go to the VSCode GitHub issues page and ask for it there: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues.

Or the last route would be to dive in and write your own plugin/extensions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview.

Comment: I already use C# for Visual Studio Code powered by OmniSharp so I can use "remove unused usings" feature by GUI operation which popup them by Ctrl + . and click on them to remove unused usings. But I want fire them on save document or I want to do them by keyboard shortcut. I understood that there is no way to this now. Currently these feature on Productivity Power Tools 2017 also not working correctly...

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is not yet available in Omnisharp. There are 2 open issues in github tracking this exact issue - https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1245 & https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1581. Lets hope the fix is released soon.